# Variable in for-loop not being reassigned each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, for-loop, parse-platform

I've got a for loop inside a for loop. The first loop should get a username, get their rating, append them to the same list item, then start over with the next username, rating, append, and so on and so forth until it's gone through ever user in the friends list.

```
//Get usernames
var current = Parse.User.current();
var relation = current.relation("FriendRelations");
relation.query().find({

success: function(results) {

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

        //This shouldn't increment until the rating has been retrieved in the
        // next function.
        theuser = results[i].getUsername();

        $('ul').prepend('<li id = "frienditems_' + i + '"><div id ="friendname">' +
        results[i].getUsername() + '</div></li>');


        //Get friend's rating.
        //This is a query within a query.
        var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Rating");
        var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
        query.equalTo("user", results[i].getUsername());
        query.find({

            success: function(result) {

                //The log just outputs the last user's name each time, because I guess the 
                //other function already looped through completely, so it's forever set to the last one?**

                console.log(theuser);

                for (var y = 0; y < result.length; y++) {
                    var object = result[y].get("Rating");

                    //Logging the rating.
                    console.log("Rating:" + object);

                    $('#frienditems_' + y).append('<p class="friendrating">' + object + '</p>');
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {}
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my console.log:

```
       John
       Rating:5
       John
       Rating:50
       John
       Rating:43
       John
       Rating:80
```

**I want it to be this:**

```
       George
       Rating:5
       Smith
       Rating:50
       Robert
       Rating:43
       John
       Rating:80
```

Can anyone help? I've looked at other questions, but I can't figure out how to apply them to my situation. I wish I could at least access the first functions results within the second function.

**UPDATE:** Mihail's answer really helped me out. The console log now shows data being retrieved in the correct order. But it's still not all appending to its respective list item:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the asynchronous call to query.find(). You practically order the browser to retrieve your information from the cloud database and tell him what to do with the result if it retrieves anything successfully, while the code continues execution (in your case, the for loop still iterates through the first collection).

By the time the first request ends, for reaches the end and because the second query's success is in the scope of the first, the variable theuser is still instantiated and has the last value available.

To prevent that, you can change the scope of the variable using a function call with your parameter. I've rewritten your code and it looks like this:

```
var current = Parse.User.current();
var relation = current.relation("FriendRelations");
var $ul = $('ul')
relation.query().find({        

    success:function(results){

        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            theuser = results[i].getUsername(); 

            // you can use <<var $friendrating = $("<li id='frienditems_" + i"'/>").html(...... >>
            var $friendrating = $(document.createElement("li")).attr("id", "frienditems_" + i).html('<div class="friendname">' + results[i].getUsername() + '</div>')
            $ul.prepend($friendrating);
            getUserRating(theuser, $friendrating);       
        }
    } 
});

function getUserRating(theUser, $node) {
    //Get friend's rating.
    //This is a query within a query.
    var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Rating");
    var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("user", theUser);
    query.find({

        success: function(result) {

            //The log just outputs the last user's name each time, because I guess the 
            //other function already looped through completely, so it's forever set to the last one?**

            console.log(theUser);

            for (var y = 0; y < result.length; y++) { 
                var object = result[y].get("Rating");

                //Logging the rating.
                console.log("Rating:" +object);

                $node.append('<p class="friendrating">' + object + '</p>');
            }
        },
        error: function(error) {
        }
    });
}
```

Please, be advised that i haven't tested it and i'm not 100% sure it will work on the first try.

Comment: Thank you so much! The console output is correct. I had actually tried something like this yesterday, but it failed because the result in the function kept returning undefined. Now my problem is that although the console log looks as it should, the ratings are not being appended to each list item. Instead, they're just all mashed together into one.

Comment: I've updated the code and this should solve the second issue. In the original code $('#frienditems_' + y) used the "y" from the second for, instead of the first. Instead of my proposal, you can pass the "i" from the first loop as a second parameter, and replace $node/$('#frienditems_' + y) with $('#frienditems_' + i), where the last "i" is the second parameter (you could change its name to index, for better readability).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out! If there's any way I can make a donation to you, or anything at all, please let me know.

Comment: Hey, mate! It's a free site where we help each other because we like to do that. I'm not doing this for money. I have a job for that. I'm happy that you solved your problem. ;)

Comment: Now this is my new problem: http://imgur.com/BAXFzLZ. For whatever reason, the ratings are one list item behind. Can you point me in the right direction? I've looked through the code a lot, and I can't find anything out of order.

Comment: Can you add some logs of the node html before and after the call of your function? Use console.log($friendrating[0].outerHTML) before and after your call to getUserRating.

Comment: Ended up being a CSS problem. Thanks! The name was set to float right, so it was pushing down the rating which was also set to float right. Embarrassing, but I'm still learning. Thanks to you, I've learned a good bit in a day.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that you solved your problem and understood why it works like this. ;)

Answer (score 1):

because the anonymous callback function `success: function(result) {}` is called after the for loop finishes in this case, query.find() is an asynchronous call, meaning the for loop will continue independently to the next iteration no matter if the query.find() has returned or not.

variable *theuser* is always the value of *theuser* in the last for loop because the for loop is able to complete before any of the callback functions are triggered